# sfdisk lists an unknown device /dev/xvda4

Tags: partition, sfdisk

When I run `sfdisk -l` on my Ubuntu 14.04 machine, it returns the following:

```
Disk /dev/xvda: 36473 cylinders, 255 heads, 63 sectors/track
Units = cylinders of 8225280 bytes, blocks of 1024 bytes, counting from 0

   Device Boot Start     End   #cyls    #blocks   Id  System
/dev/xvda1          0+    522     523-   4200966   83  Linux
/dev/xvda2        523     784     262    2104515   82  Linux swap / Solaris
/dev/xvda3        785   36473-  35689- 286664983+  8e  Linux LVM
                end: (c,h,s) expected (1023,254,63) found (633,35,42)
/dev/xvda4          0       -       0          0    0  Empty

...
```

I am suprised about the `/dev/xvda4` entry: There is no entry for it when listing the `/dev/` directory, and other commands such as `parted -l` and `lsblk` don't reference that device either.

What does `sfdisk -l` show with that `/dev/xvda4` entry?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This disk appears to use the [traditional PC partitioning type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disk_partitioning#PC_partition_types), also known as MBR. In the MBR format, there are exactly four primary partitions, no more, no less: the partition table in the first sector of the disk has four entries. An entry can be marked with type 0, meaning unused. `fdisk -l` (like many other tools) omits entries in the primary partition table that are unused. `sfdisk -l` lists those partitions and indicates that they're empty.